# How to jump to error line in eclipse editor from my created view

Tags: eclipse, view

I have created a view in eclipse like console and it shows the errors to users.So when user clicks on that error it should go to that line number.How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Throw away your selfmade view, implement the [console factory extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_console_consoleFactories.html) instead to create new console sub windows in the existing console view. Afterwards implement the [console pattern match extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_console_consoleFactories.html) to find and link text segments in the console output.

Implementing a full view in Eclipse that behaves like an already existing view is always wrong. All of the existing views in the eclipse platform have extension points to change and enhance them. Nobody really wants to have 5 *different* console views being shown in a perspective.